# MongoDB populate items before $pull condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Users collection:

```
[
  {
    _id: '5b3935c2d4850aa2d9f0ae25',
    feedBucket: ['5b37d16665c4127e7a088812', '5b3a19c5be4949b0d74476d4']
  },
{
    _id: '35c2d4850aa2d9f0ae25ab39',
    feedBucket: ['5b37d16665c4127e7a088812', '5b3a19c5be4949b0d74476d4']
  }
]
```

Post collection:

```
[
  {
    _id: '5b37d16665c4127e7a088812',
    createdAt: 2018-07-01 23:12:50.232
  },
  {
    _id: '5b3a19c5be4949b0d74476d4',
    createdAt: 2018-05-01 23:12:50.232
  },
]
```

I want to execute following:

```
const date = new Date()
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1)

await User.updateMany(
  {},
  { $pull: { feedBucket: { createdAt: { $lte: date } } } }
)
```

Is there any way to populate feedBucket items before $pull condition?
Or feedBucket shouldn't be an array of items ids, but should be an array of item documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below:

```
const postsToPull = await Post.find({ createdAt: { $lte: date } });
await User.updateMany(
  {},
  { $pull: { feedBucket: { $in: postsToPull } }
)
```

Another option is to store `createdAt` within `feedBucket` like

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    createdAt: Date
}
```

Then you can query it with

```
await User.updateMany(
  {},
  { $pull: { feedBucket: { createdAt: { $lte: date } } } }
)
```